# Why do i get 'command not found' even after installing Expo completes successfully?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have installed Expo-CLI and have the metro bundler running in localhost correctly. I also have an existing Expo account. However when I navigate into the expo project i created and type in any expo related command, it responds like Expo is totally foreign:

[image]

Can someone help me figure out what's missing here and how to resolve it please?

Answer (score 0):

Add the path for the expo-cli to your system.

If you're using Windows then just follow these steps.

1. Press Windows Key and search for ***Edit the system environment variables***
2. Go to ***Environment Variables***
3. Go to ***User Variable for***
4. Go to **Path**
5. Press ***New***
6. Add ***%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm*** to the path
7. Restart your cmd/powershell
8. Try writing `expo --version` to see the version and voila it's working!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue couple of days before, the solution that I found out is to keep "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm" as the only path for npm global installation
to check the global path for npm, you can use `npm config get prefix`,
to set the global path for npm ,you can use `npm config set prefix %PATH%`

after that run npm install and everything will be working !